# c++ build error

Tags: c++

I am trying to integrate wwise into a test project. I have a project on windows 7 using ms visual studio 2010  and this is the error I get after I try and add a necassary cpp to the project. i dont get this build error on my machine at home with the same set up, what does it mean?

```
------ Build started: Project: wwise test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  AkFilePackageLUT.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.2.1 build 4427\sdk\samples\soundengine\common\akfilepackagelut.h(204): error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
      c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.2.1 build 4427\sdk\samples\soundengine\common\akfilepackagelut.cpp(117) : see reference to function template instantiation 'const CAkFilePackageLUT::AkFileEntry<T_FILEID> *CAkFilePackageLUT::LookupFile<AkFileID>(T_FILEID,const CAkFilePackageLUT::FileLUT<T_FILEID> *,bool)' being compiled
      with
      [
          T_FILEID=AkFileID
      ]
c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.2.1 build 4427\sdk\samples\soundengine\common\akfilepackagelut.h(204): error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
      c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.2.1 build 4427\sdk\samples\soundengine\common\akfilepackagelut.cpp(140) : see reference to function template instantiation 'const CAkFilePackageLUT::AkFileEntry<T_FILEID> *CAkFilePackageLUT::LookupFile<AkUInt64>(T_FILEID,const CAkFilePackageLUT::FileLUT<T_FILEID> *,bool)' being compiled
      with
      [
          T_FILEID=AkUInt64
      ]
```

Comment: it means, well that `'NULL' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: If you read the error message again, it tells you that it can't find the identifier `NULL`. This should tell you that you are missing the header file that defines `NULL` (should be `<cstddef>`).

Comment: the source can't be modified so i cant use nullptr. @aleguna i'm looking for an answer with more detail. where is null declared, what possible error would mean that a file expecting it to be declared cant link to its declaration, and whether its also affecting the other error.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks on the first glance like you did not specify a template parameter .

Other possible causes:

- You are compiling with a debug version of the C runtime, declaring a
  Standard C++ Library iterator variable in a for loop, and then
  trying to use that iterator variable outside the scope of the for
  loop. Compiling Standard C++ Library code with a debug version of
  the C runtime implies /Zc:forScope. See Debug Iterator Support for
  more information.
- You may be calling a function in an SDK header file that is
  currently not supported in your build environment.
- Omitting necessary include files, especially if you define
     VC_EXTRALEAN, WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN, or WIN32_EXTRA_LEAN. These
     symbols exclude some header files from windows.h and afxv_w32.h to
     speed compiles. (Look in windows.h and afxv_w32.h for an up-to-date
     description of what's excluded.)
- Identifier name is misspelled.
- Identifier uses the wrong uppercase and lowercase letters.
- Missing closing quote after a string constant.
- Improper namespace scope. To resolve ANSI C++ Standard Library
     functions and operators, for example, you must specify the std
     namespace with the using directive. The following example fails to
     compile because the using directive is commented out and cout is
     defined in the std namespace

Answer (score 1):

This error message is saying the following:

in `<path...>\akfilepackagelut.h` there is a definition of a function template. In fact, it is a templated method of a class. Inside that definition, on line 204, the name `NULL` is used. `NULL` is defined in header `<cstddef>` of the C standard library, and normally you can include that definition by including one of a lot of C/C++ headers, because most of them somehow include `<cstddef>`. However, `akfilepackagelut.h` seems to include only headers that in the VS2012 installation you are using do *not* include that definition, so the compiler does not know what NULL means.

The whole rest of the error message is just template error gibberish, telling you that that function template we are talking about has been instantiated twice somewhere in `AkFilePackageLUT.cpp`, telling you the exact locations and the template parameters and so on.

What can you do? 
Well, if you can not modify the source as you say (Why? You *have* the source) you can't do anything but perhaps file a bug for the project. If you can modify it would be best to `#include <cstddef>` in `akfilepackagelut.h`.